# Trying to add array to hash table so that I can see if elements match in a different array

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I am trying to compare two arraylist and I am doing so using a nested loop. Instead I want to iterate through the first array and add the elements to a hashtable so that the hash table will be equal to

```
{a: true, f: true, t: true, y: true}
```

Then I want to iterate through the second array to see if any of the elements in the second array exist in the first array.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object[] array1 = {"a","f","t","y"};
        Object[] array2 = {"b","u","g","a","d","f"};


        findMatch(array1, array2);
    }
    public static void findMatch(Object[] a,Object[] b ){
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < b.length; j++){
                if(a[i].equals(b[j])){
                    System.out.println("match");
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I updated the question let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: what's your point?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest you narrow down the types for you array so you don't run into run time type error. In your case, you should make them arrays of string.

If you just want to check whether something exists in both arrays. You could just use a set instead of hash table and then iterates through second array and prints out the match.

```
Set<String> matches = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array1));

for(String s : array2){
    if(matches.contains(s){
        System.out.println("match");
    }
}
```

The idea is the same if you really do wanna compare objects, but you should be aware that when you compare two `Obect`, the `equals` method checks whether the two things reside at the same memory location, meaning they are the same objects. It would work just fine when your arrays are actually strings because of string interning (provided you don't use `new` to create your strings). But it might not work for other types if you don't explicit override `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. what if i need to pass the arrays through the same function. would i just loop through array1 and add its elements to the hashset. then loop through array2 shown above in your answer?